# Getting standard Cartesian coordinate axes for 3d matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm running the following code to plot a parametrized curve in 3d:

```
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot(p[:,0], p[:,1], p[:,2], label='Trajectory')
ax.legend()
ax.axis([0, 2, 0, 2])
plt.show()
```

where p[,] contains my coordinates. The code gives me the following graph:

[image: parametrized curve matplotlib]

I'd like for instead of the weird inverted axes in this graph to just have my curve plotted on normal 3 dimensional Cartesian coordinates, i.e. something like this (excuse my artistic limitations):
[image: cartesian coordinates]

where the axes all start at (0,0,0) and increase outwards from it.

I'm unsure what to do to get this.

Comment: Hi ! What I see right now is a normal cartesian space with the origin at the bottom left of the image. It seems like only the legends of the axes are (visually) a bit weird, because they couldn't display them "behind" the 3D plot, so they put them at the front.
If that was not your question, could you please clarify ?

Comment: Oh you're right, I just got confused by the labelling. Thanks haha

Comment: Np have fun programming !